# Can SSIS be configured in Development and then transferred over to the Production Database?

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I have a project where I have to migrate data from one database to another. We have a copy of the database on our development server and I am planning to use SSIS with Visual Studio to do this. I have set up Connection Managers with data flows and control flows.

How do i configure it such that all i have to do in the future is to change a setting and that will allow me to run the package from my DEV database to my Production one with ease? Will it be as easy as re-configuring the connection managers? If I try to add a new Connection Manager and point it to that, all my mappings seems to dissapear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should utilise SSIS configuration to make portable between environments

- [Best Practices for Integration Services Configurations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc671628.aspx)

There are several options including xml files, command line options etc.

- Command line options (`/SET`)
- XML configuration file
- Environment variable
- Registry entry
- Parent package variable
- SQL Server

See [Package Configurations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141682.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I've figured out how to use XML Configuration Files.

Comment: Any tips on which options above are the best? A friend recommended SQL Server but I haven't played around with that option yet

Comment: There is no "best" option, everyone has their own opinion and different options suit different scenarios. Personally I like to use XML config files as they are simple, human readable and easily portable.